# Prove $\ln(1+x^{2})=\arctan x$ has two solutions in $\Bbb{R}$. How do I finish my proof?

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

**Attempt**:
Define a function $g(x)=\ln(1+x^{2})-\arctan x$.
Then $g'(x)={2x\over 1+x^2}-{1\over 1+x^2}$ and $x={1\over2}$ is a potential extremum.
$g''(x)={-2x^2+2x+2\over (1+x)^4} \Rightarrow g''({1\over 2})>0 \Rightarrow x={1\over 2}$ is a maximum point and the only extremum of $g$.
$g({1\over 2})<0$ since $\ln(x)\le x$ and $\arctan{1\over 2} > {1\over 2}$. Since $g(x)$ as a subtraction of two continuous functions is continuous and given there are no additional extremums, either the function crosses the $x$ axis twice (which sort of completes the proof) or the function tends to $y=0$ as $x\to \pm \infty$.

How do I finish it?

Comment: $g''(1/2)>0$ means minima.

Comment: Yes.. My wrong.

Comment: A minor point:  the denominator in $g''(x)$ should be $(1+x^2)^2$, not $(1+x)^4$.

Answer (score 1):

In fact $x=\frac{1}{2}$ is a minimum and is negative. Now look at the limit of the function when $x\rightarrow -\infty$ and $x\rightarrow +\infty$, which are both $\infty$. Also the derivative before $\frac{1}{2}$ and after $\frac{1}{2}$ are negative and positive, respectively. So there exists one root between $-\infty$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ and another between $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\infty$.

Comment: I think the limits at $\pm \infty$ both equal to $\infty$

Comment: Since $\arctan$ is bounded and $\ln(1+x^2) \to +\infty$ for $x\to\pm\infty$, @user160738 is correct.

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Going to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $g''(x) > 0, g'(x) = 0$ implies that $x$ is a local *minimum* (not maximum).
Since $\arctan$ is bounded by $\frac\pi2$ above and below, the asymptotic behaviour is dominated by $\ln(1+x^2) \to\infty$ as $|x|\to\infty$.
Now you must use that $g$ is actually of class $C^1$ ($g'$ is also continuous) because this is necessary to guarantee that the function can't "turn around" without attaining a local maximum with $g'=0$ (according to the MVT, the existence of two roots implies that the derivative is $0$ somewhere between them as long as $g$ is $C^1$). So you compile

> $g'(x) = 0 \Rightarrow x=\frac12$, $g\in C^1(\mathbb R)$ and $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} g(x) = \infty$

This implies $g(x) = 0$ has exactly two solutions, one in each of $(-\infty, \frac12)$ and $(\frac12, \infty)$.

---

The long conclusion:
By the definition of divergence, we can find $x_1>\frac12$ such that $g(x_1), g(-x_1) > 0$.
Since $g$ is continuous, the IVT guarantees us at least one root in each of $(-x_1, \frac12)$ and $(\frac12, x_1)$.
Let us now assume there were at least two roots, $z_1 < z_2$ within one of the intervals. Since $g'$ is continuous as well, we can use the MVT noting that $0 = \frac{g(z_2)-g(z_1)}{z_2-z_1}$ so we know there is $x_2 \in (z_1,z_2)$ such that $g'(x_2) = 0$.
But $\frac12\notin (z_1,z_2)$, so this is a contradiciton to $g'$ having only the root $\frac12$.
This shows us that there can't be two (or more) distinct roots in any of the two intervals, i.e. there is *exactly* one root in each of $(-x_1, \frac12) \subset (-\infty, \frac12)$ and $(\frac12, x_1) \subset (\frac12, \infty)$.

QED

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, it is way better to replace $x$ with $\tan t$ and prove that
$$ f(t)=-2\log|\cos t| = t \tag{1}$$
has two solutions over $I=(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. A solution is obviously located in $t=0$ and the other one is somewhere near $\pi/2$ (between $0.86$ and $0.87$) since the LHS of $(1)$ is a convex function over $I$ (since $f'(t)=2\tan t$ is increasing over $I$) and 
$$\lim_{x\to\pm\pi/2}-2\log|\cos t| = +\infty.$$

Answer (score 1):

for the function $g$ defined by $g(x)= \ln(1+x^2) - \tan^{-1} x,$ here are few things we know and need about $g$:

(a) $g(0) = 0, g = -x + \cdots \text{ for } x = 0 + \cdots$

(b) $\dfrac{dg}{dx} = \dfrac{2x - 1}{1 + x^2}$

(c) $g(x) \to \infty \text{ as } x \to \pm \infty, g = 2\ln(|x|) + \cdots \text{ at } x = \pm \infty  $

by  rolle's theorem $g$ can have at most two zeros. knowing $g(0) = 0, g^\prime(0) = -1, \lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) = \infty$ and an application of the intermediate value theorem gives you the unique positive  zero of $g$.